# No of subsets of a given array such that their product is in the form of p1*p2*p3

Tags: array, primes

Given an array \$A\$ of size \$n\$.
You have to find the number of subsets such that their product is in the form of \$p_1 \times p_2 \times p_3 \dots\$
where \$p_1, p_2, p_3, \dots\$ are prime numbers. No prime number should appear more than once, i.e. the product is "squarefree".

Example:
Lets pick an array \$A\$ of size \$5\$. \$A[5] = \{2, 3, 15, 55, 21\}\$
The subsets in our answers should be \$\{2,3\}, \{2, 15\}, \{2, 55\}, \{2, 21\}, \{2, 3, 55\}, \{2, 55, 21\}, \{3, 55\}, \{55, 21\}\$.
Lets take \$\{2, 3, 55\}\$ The product will be \$2 \times 3 \times 55 = 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 11\$. Thus all prime numbers with power of 1.
We can't take for example \$\{3, 15\}\$ because \$3 \times 15 = 3^2 \times 5\$. Condition not satisfied.
Therefore our answer should be number of subsets i.e. here 8.

Constraints: \$2\leq A_i<10^9\$,
\$1\leq n<10^5\$

Comment: [Welcome to CGCC](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange). Please read [how to ask](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20862/68942) - your question right now is missing several details; the wording could be more clear but I understood the body of the challenge, but it is missing a scoring criterion. I would advise drafting your challenge in [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) before posting in the future; it's helpful for getting feedback first.

Comment: Note that the term you are likely looking for, to describe the products, is "squarefree" - that is, 42 is squarefree because there is no square factor except 1, while 45 is not squarefree because 9 is a factor, and 9 is square.

Comment: Looks like the question simply asks for [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) subsets of A.

Comment: If you are asking for code-golf, you should include it in question (typically add a sentence "This is code-golf, shortest codes in bytes win." to question body) and add a [tag:code-golf] tag. Currently, this question is off-topic as challenges here must have [an objective scoring criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria).

Comment: May input array contain duplicate numbers? What is expected output for \$A[4]=\left\{2,2,3,3\right\}\$?

Comment: @pajonk That would be different if input array contains numbers already multiple of square numbers. For example, \$A\left[3\right]=\left\{2,3,4\right\}\$.

Comment: This is a great challenge in my opinion, just needs to be improved with an objective scoring criterion (ideally code-golf) and a few more test cases. Perhaps also work your example a little better by including every possible subset or at least 3 invalid subsets and explaining why they do not satisfy the conditions.

Comment: @tsh Consider distinct elements in the array

Comment: @tsh what is objective scoring criterion

Comment: What is the source of this question? It really looks like it was copied from a programming site.

Comment: @xnor it was a job hiring challenge. I didn't get it in any programming site.

Comment: An "objective scoring criteria" is a way to assign a score to any given answer that does not rely on feelings or opinions, just on facts. The most common and easy to implement would be [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) (as suggested by Recursive Co.)

Comment: I think the empty subset and all the square-free singleton sets also fit the description given but these are not listed in your example, so either they need adding to the example or the description needs updating somehow.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 16 bytes

```
ṗ'L1>;ƛΠǐ:UL$L"≈
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%E1%B9%97%27L1%3E%3B%C6%9B%CE%A0%C7%90%3AUL%24L%22%E2%89%88&inputs=%5B2%2C%203%2C%2015%2C%2055%2C%2021%5D&header=&footer=)